# Using python vcr with Google Video Intelligence - error with request

Tags: python, google-apps, vcr, video-intelligence-api

I'm having a strange google video intelligence api request error when I run a test with python vcr.  I was wondering if anyone else has seen this error, and if so, why we have this and how to solve it?

I use VCR to mock the request to video intelligence api.

I use pytest to run my test.

If I delete the VCR and rerun it runs fine, and if I try running it again after vcr is created it also runs fine.  However after a while, (not currently sure if this is hours or days, I will get the error below from running the vcr).

The error is below:-

```
"Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
```

This is the VCR error

```
    E   google.api_core.exceptions.Unauthenticated: 401 Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
    <string>:3: Unauthenticated
    Assertion failed
```

Comment: GCP client libraries will automatically re-fetch user credentials for you, using your service account. It does this before the credentials expire. The credentials expire after some time (not exactly sure how long, maybe an hour or so). I'm not familiar with VCR, but it sounds like it's something related to your real credentials (access token) expiring and failing to re-fetch a new access token, rather than the API call to Video Intelligence. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

## EDIT1

The simplest solution to this problem is to ensure that the API does not use gRPC.

```
vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(transport="rest")
```

This will allow the API to utilize RESTful endpoints without causing any disruptions to VCR.

## Original Response

Google Vision Intelligence just like other google service, use gRPC to communicate with service backend. Unfortunately, VCR does not support gRPC yet.

The only thing VCR recorded during test is OAuth token (checked the cassettes file VCR generated). When it expired, it will cause the `Unauthenticated` Error

### reference:

- Feature request about gRPC support
  https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy/issues/560
- VCR for gRPC (Ruby) https://github.com/btoews/gcr

Comment: great to know. do you know any alternative Python library with gRPC support for mocking calls to Google APIs?

Comment: @AgileBean unlucky, I didn't find any yet. But I figure out a way to force Google APIs to use RESTful endpoint which can work correctly with VCR. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [error](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/faq#why_does_my_request_have_invalid_authentication_credentials) seems to point towards invalid authentication credentials.

There might be two possible scenarios behind this error -

You can follow the below mentioned steps to verify the initial setup configuration you have made :

****Solution1-**   For Custom Service account i.e user-managed service accounts:**

- If you have created a service account of your own then you will need to generate the keys for that service account.
- You also need to set the Environment variables using:

  **“export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="KEY_PATH”**

**Solution2-     Application Default Credentials** are not available:

**For Default Service accounts** ( projects which have enabled the Compute Engine API will have a Compute Engine default service account which will use the Application Default Credentials ), you can follow the below mentioned steps:

- You need to log in using the [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) : **gcloud auth application-default login**
- If you want to make sure that the [authentication process](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token) went well then run : **gcloud auth application-default print-access-token**. You should be able to see an access token.
- Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to obtain new access tokens.
- Basically gcloud auth application-default login acquires credentials to make them available to the applications in your local machine to use when they are configured to use **Application Default Credentials**.